# Computing entire mapping of homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Suppose $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $S_4$ to $S_3$. It is given that $\phi (12)=(13)$ and $\phi (234)=(132)$. Compute the entire mapping $\phi$.

$S_4= \{ (), (12), (13), (14), (23), (24), (34), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23), (123), (124), (134), (234), (143), (243), (132), (142), (1234), (1324), (1423), (1432), (1342), (1243) \}$

You can do $\phi (12) \phi (234) =\phi (1342)=(13)(132)=(12) $ and maybe do similar calculations but it might take a while.

I feel like once I calculate the mapping of $(12), (13), (14), (23), (24), (34) $ then I can compute everything easily and not miss anything but I how do I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permutations $(1 2)$ and $(2 3 4)$ form a set of generators of $S_4$. To find the image of an arbitrary element of $S_4$, first write that element as a product of the generators (and their inverses).

Example, using the convention that composition goes from the left to the right:

$(1 3) = (2 3 4)^{-1} (1 2) (2 3 4)$

$\phi(1 3) = (1 3 2)^{-1} (1 3) (1 3 2) = (2 3)$

Comment: could you edit it so that its left to right please because that is how we do them. I find it really confusing if it is the opposite.

Comment: done btw my first answer was wrong even with the right-to-left convention

Comment: is there any way to check all my mappings?